# Всё сам: вопрос, ответ, оценка, приём - правильно? приемлемо?

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка

Я на Вашем (НАШЕМ) Форуме не так давно, всего три месяца.
Не сразу, - но меня очень удивила ситуация: САМ задам вопрос - САМ на него отвечу - САМ его "приму" (оценю).
В основном, это вопросы - ответы "нескольколетней" давности.
**КТО** их - правильные, неправильные, сомнительные, спорные, дублированные - отслеживает, корректирует, удаляет через энное количество лет?
Вот сегодня, конкретно:

[**шиворот навыворот**](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/394/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82):
задан - 05.01.12 - 12.08
ответ - (сам себе) 05.01.12 - 12.10

[**шиворот-навыворот**](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/45618/%D0%97%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%A8%D0%98%D0%92%D0%9E%D0%A0%D0%9E%D0%A2-%D0%9D%D0%90%D0%92%D0%AB%D0%92%D0%9E%D0%A0%D0%9E%D0%A2)

Очень даже понятно, что любой, "забредший" на сайт, будет сомневаться - А КАК ПРАВИЛЬНО? - если вопросов: два, и оба - "приняты"!
Нонсенс. Как быть? Что делать с этими [относительно - правильными] ответами?

P.S. Специально не искала, но, если еще обнаружу, - дополню.

Дополнение: [**вперемеШку или вперемеЖку?**](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/1/%D0%92%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%A8%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%96%D0%BA%D1%83)
Дополнение(-1): [**"на ощупь" или "наощупь"?**](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/347/%D0%9D%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%8C)
Дополнение: [**выпить "чая" или выпить "чаю"?**](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/662/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%8E)
Дополнение: [**"гривна" или "гривня"?**](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/1282/%D0%93%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8F)
Дополнение: [**Этимология слова "Москва"**](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/699/%D0%AD%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0)

P.P.S. Мне кажется, что достаточно: не буду больше "рыть"...

Answer (score 3):

Дубликаты объединил, справедливости ради там ответы одни и те же, различаются только степенью развернутости.

Теперь по поводу этих вопросов. До того как форум раскрутился, чтобы он не выглядел пустым, модератор Fuchoin Kazuki создавала множество аккаунтов и задавала с них вопросы, имитируя активность пользователей. В первое время ей иногда даже приходилось отвечать на них самой, чтобы вопросы не остались без ответа. После переезда на новую платформу все эти аккаунты объединили и поэтому может создаться ощущение, что у пользователя раздвоение личности похлеще чем в фильме "Сплит", так как она говорит о себе то в мужском роде, то в женском, то из Крыма, то с Чукотки и т. д.

Удалять эти вопросы не вижу смысла, так как ответы в них по большей части верные. Да и этимология Fuchoin Kazuki в основном интересовала, а по этой тематике задают вопросы не так часто, но её ищут, так что база подобных вопросов сообществу не повредит.

Теперь, что касается ответов на собственные вопросы. Такое возможно, если автор вопроса разобрался в рассматриваемой проблеме сам и хочет этим поделиться с остальными пользователями. У меня, например, есть [ответ](https://rus.stackexchange.com/a/32856/1067) на собственный вопрос, который пользователи оценили также высоко как ответ, выбранный мною лучшим. Если выбрать свой ответ лучшим, очки рейтинга за него не добавляются и в верх списка этот ответ не становится, поэтому ставить галочку у него имеет смысл лишь тогда, когда остальные до собственного ответа явно не дотягивают.

Answer (score 1):

Не могу согласиться с *Марк Из*ом.

**1.** *Дубликаты объединил, справедливости ради там ответы одни и те же, различаются только степенью развернутости.*

Не совсем верно: **"шиворот навыворот" -**
*"шиворот-навыворот" пишется через дефис – М_Г 15 янв в 15:25* (комментарий) - через три года.

**2.** *Удалять эти вопросы не вижу смысла, так как ответы в них **по большей части верные.***

**“На ощупь” или “наощупь”?** - ответ неверный, с отрицательным рейтингом, НО! - принят: *Тем не менее, слово "на ощупь", согласно нормам русского языка, пишется слитно.*

Есть комментарий: *Не ответ. Надо бы убрать или объяснить себе и другим. – shampar 17 мар '16 в 20:07* - через четыре года.

КОМУ - тем не менее? Ответу с рейтингом [+6] - развернутому и абсолютно противоположному?

**3.** *...если автор вопроса разобрался в рассматриваемой проблеме сам и хочет этим поделиться с остальными пользователями.

...ставить галочку у него имеет смысл лишь тогда, когда остальные до собственного ответа явно не дотягивают.*

**Выпить “чая” или выпить “чаю”?**
Ответ: *В русском языке правомерны оба варианта.*

**Этимология слова “Москва”**
Ответ: *Есть множество гипотез на этот счет, но самая распространенная - это родство слова "москва" и "промозглый", то есть, холодны сырой. То есть, слово "москва" обозначает низменность, сырое место.*

***Где же тут "разборки" в проблеме, высокий уровень, ссылки, цитаты?***

**4.** Я никак не призываю **изничтожить всё и вся.** Просто мне кажется, что **пришло время рассмотреть эти проблемы: они многих путают, вызывают непонимание и сомнения, а отсюда - и недоверие к Форуму.**

Вопросов у *Fuchoin Kazuki* - более двух тысяч, конечно, не все они "самоприняты".
Достойные - оставляем принятыми, спорные - "галочку" убираем, чтобы она никого не смущала.
*Есть **модераторы**, есть участники **с глобальными знаниями и репутацией** - кому как не им на МЕТЕ заняться этим делом!? **Понемножку.***

Comment: У модераторов нет полномочий снимать галочку лучшего ответа, а удалять ответы не за что, пусть они и не полные, но своевременные. Вопрос о том нужно модераторам удалять неверные ответы сейчас обсуждается на Мете, но, к сожалению, кроме меня в вопросе пока никто не высказался.

Comment: Своевременно - не есть правильно!